# Is there a way to set automatic properties in secondary constructors?

Tags: f#

I have this class:

```
type Sample() =
    member val test1 = "" with get,set
    member val test2 = "" with get,set

    // is something like the below constructor possible
    new Sample(result1, result2) =
        this.test1 <- "failed"
        this.test2 <- "passed"
        Sample()
```

I've tried several different ways, but I can not get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mark Seemann's answer is the proper solution, but you can get exactly what you want using this odd construction:

```
type Sample() =
    member val test1 = "" with get,set
    member val test2 = "" with get,set

    new (result1, result2) as sample =
        Sample()
            then
                sample.test1 <- result1
                sample.test2 <- result2
```

But truth be told, this is something I have never used myself, likely never seen used in the wild and more of a language-trivia sort of thing than anything else.

Comment: Huh. I suppose that's because the arguments were not used (which is also what OP's code did).

Comment: @Mark Seemann, Sorry, but what you expect it to do? https://dotnetfiddle.net/wq711M

Comment: This is perfectly valid, but it will result in runtime initialization checks in the compiled code, which is a small perf hit.

Comment: @FoggyFinder I would have expected it to do *sensible* initialization, like not throwing away the constructor arguments, but I realise that perhaps I've slightly misread the OP...

Comment: @FoggyFinder: check the previous revision - the properties were set to hardcoded strings instead (which I took from OP's code, but it likely wasn't the intent there so I edited it). Anyway, that's not the point here - the syntax for the constructor is.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want?

```
type Sample(result1, result2) =
    member val Test1 = result1 with get,set
    member val Test2 = result2 with get,set
    new () = Sample("failed", "passed")
```

FSI:

```
> Sample();;
val it : Sample = FSI_0002+Sample {Test1 = "failed";
                                   Test2 = "passed";}
> Sample("foo", "bar");;
val it : Sample = FSI_0002+Sample {Test1 = "foo";
                                   Test2 = "bar";}
```

Comment: Well I am aware that it can be done that way in the primary constructor, but I was just curious if it were possible the other way around.